# Kubernetes 1.7 calico log message calico-node -felix-live -bird-live] and timeout 1 (s)

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I am running Kubernetes 1.17 cluster with Calico CNI running on containerd. my servers are running CentOS 8, all my nodes I am getting this log message. how to stop these messages?

```
Mar  8 21:15:48 node03 systemd[1]: Removed slice libcontainer_14289_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:48 node03 containerd[1400]: time="2020-03-08T21:15:48.641993033-04:00" level=info msg="ExecSync for "a5e553ee2fd117b0724f56fd9606031f187f4ca0aa468c31f90690f305f49a89" returns with exit code 0"
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 containerd[1400]: time="2020-03-08T21:15:50.606510411-04:00" level=info msg="ExecSync for "a5e553ee2fd117b0724f56fd9606031f187f4ca0aa468c31f90690f305f49a89" with command [/bin/calico-node -felix-live -bird-live] and timeout 1 (s)"
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14399-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14399-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer_14399_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Removed slice libcontainer_14399_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14405-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14405-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer_14405_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Removed slice libcontainer_14405_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14411-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14411-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer_14411_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Removed slice libcontainer_14411_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14417-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14417-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer_14417_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Removed slice libcontainer_14417_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14437-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: libcontainer-14437-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope: Scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer_14437_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 systemd[1]: Removed slice libcontainer_14437_systemd_test_default.slice.
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 containerd[1400]: time="2020-03-08T21:15:50.775530563-04:00" level=info msg="Exec process "1f990c60ac0163d4a69c3ac6d2c1c2c53458d872e3d7e950cb89bcf2365c4601" exits with exit code 0 and error <nil>"
Mar  8 21:15:50 node03 containerd[1400]: time="2020-03-08T21:15:50.775615176-04:00" level=info msg="Finish piping "stdout" of container exec "1f990c60ac0163d4a69c3ac6d2c1c2c53458d872e3d7e950cb89bcf2365c4601""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already opened issue on Github, more details can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71887).

This issue is related with `cgroup-driver`. In newest Kubernetes version is set to `systemd` instead of `cgroupfs`.

One workaround is to configure `rsyslog`. Steps are well sescribed on [this site](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/recurring-messages-complain-scope-libcontainer-nnnnn-has-no-pids-refusing). Below short version:

```
$ cd /etc/rsyslog.d
```

Create a file `ignore-systemd-session-slice.conf` with content:

```
if ($programname == "systemd") and ($msg contains "_systemd_test_default.slice" or $msg contains "systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope") then {
  stop
}
```

After that service rsyslog must be restarted.

```
$ service rsyslog restart
```

Another way is to use `cgroupfs` as `cgroup-driver`.
This also was discussed on [this Github thread](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30628).

---

added these to ignore the logs

`cat  /etc/rsyslog.d/ignore-systemd-session-slice.conf` file

```
if ($programname == "systemd") and ($msg contains "_systemd_test_default.slice" or $msg contains "systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope" or $msg contains " Failed to get system container stats for") then {
  stop
}
if ($programname == "kubelet") and ($msg contains " Failed to get system container stats for" or $msg contains "test_default.slice") then {
  stop
}

if ($programname == "systemd") and ($msg contains "Starting Session" or $msg contains "Started Session" or $msg contains "Created slice" or $msg contains "Starting user-" or $msg contains "Starting User Slice of" or $msg contains "Removed session" or $msg contains "Removed slice User Slice of" or $msg contains "Stopping User Slice of") then {
        stop
}
if ($programname == "containerd") and ($msg regex "Exec process.*with exit code 0" or $msg regex "ExecSync for.*with exit code 0" or $msg contains "Finish piping") then {
  stop
}
```

Comment: I thought this issue only one CentOS 7 with docker.  I am using CentOS 8 with containerd, no docker.  not sure its same issue or something different.